# DoxyPy - Member (variable) of namespace is not documented

Tags: python, doxygen

I get the error message `warning: Member constant1 (variable) of namespace <file_name> is not documented.` for my doxygen (doxypy) documentation. I have documented the file and all functions and classes. But I also have some additional constants in this file which I don't know how to document and I get the error message. The file looks like this:

```
"""\file
\brief <this is what the file contains>
\author <author>
"""

import numpy as np

constant1 = 24
constant2 = 48

def someFunction():
    """ Doxygen documentation of someFunction() """
    <body>
```

In this example, how do I document `constant1` and`constant2`, so that the error message goes away?

Comment: Please check the paragraph "Comment blocks in Python" in the doxygen manual. Document it with "##" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@albert was right. It works when putting a `##` in front of the variables. I didn't find a solution using the `"""` syntax.

```
"""\file
\brief <this is what the file contains>
\author <author>
"""

import numpy as np

## Doxygen documentation for constant1
constant1 = 24

## Doxygen documentation for constant2
constant2 = 48

def someFunction():
    """ Doxygen documentation of someFunction() """
    <body>
```

Comment: Maybe `"""!` will help here.

Answer (score 0):

If you need (because of any reason) to have more documentation for those members, you can also split the text into several lines. It will be treated as `"""` block.

```
## Doxygen documentation for constant1. The way which you already found.
constant1 = 24
## Doxygen documentation for constant2.
#  If you need to write a lot about constant2, you can split the text into
#  several lines in this way.
constant2 = 48
```